# Stopping nexposeconsole service from launching at startup?

Tags: linux, boot, services, kali-linux

I have recently installed the vulnerability scanner Nexpose on Kali Linux Rolling.

So far everything is working good. Unfortunately the installation made `nexserv` and `nsc.sh` run on startup. I can see this is my System Monitor.

I don't want to run Nexpose every time the system, as it uses a lot of resources and I will not be accessing Nexpose daily. Therefor I just want to start the service with `service nexposeconsole start` when I need to.

The issue is I can't find how to disable this.
Here is what I have tried:

- `update-rc.d -f nsc.sh remove`, `update-rc.d -f nexserv remove`,
  `update-rc.d -f nexposeconsole remove`, and `nexposeconsole.service`.
- `sysv-rc-conf` and couldn't related services..
- `service --status-all` and couldn't find related services.
- The only thing that did
  work was `rm /etc/systemd/system/nexposeconsole.service`
  (obviously).

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that (to my knowledge) this is apart of one service called `systemctl`.

To disable an application within the system we use the command `sudo systemctl disable application_name.service`. In my case, `sudo systemctl disable nexposeconsole.service`.

More information on this [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units).

I hope this helps anyone who runs into the same issues.